# Explanation of exam question on what looks like the handshake lemma.

Tags: graph-theory

The question goes as follows:
The total degree of an undirected graph **G** = (**V, E**) is the sum of the degrees of all the vertices in **V**. Prove that if the total degree of **G** is even then **V** will contain an even number of vertices with uneven degrees.

It seems to be a misstatement of the handshake lemma, so I provided a counter-example. A graph with three vertices, where *v0* is connected to *v1* and *v2* is disconnected. This gives a graph with an ***even*** degree yet an ***uneven*** number of vertices, which is a counter-example.

There must be something that I am not understanding, could someone provide some commentary?

Comment: It seems strange to write "if the total degree of G is even", since it will be equal to $2 |E|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The graph in question has an odd number of vertices, but that does not contradict the theorem. The theorem says that it will have an even number of vertices **with odd degrees**, which it does: it has two, namely, $v_0$ and $v_1$, each of degree $1$.

Comment: Ah, yes that is what I was missing. Thank you. Sometimes you need fresh eyes on something so simple.

Comment: @niobe: You’re welcome.